# Selenium Cucumber Fails to Check for Image

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, gherkin, cucumberjs

I was trying to test one of my web application using `selenium-cucumber-js`.

I have a Feature file written using the Gherkin syntax.

```
Feature: UPS XXX Troubleshooting

#
##Chatbot must start automatically
Scenario: Chatbot automatically says hello
Given a chat window "localhost:3000/"
Then the text displayed in position "1" shall contain following statements
 | statement                                                                                                                             |
 | Hey there! I’m a bot that can help you troubleshoot issues with UPS.                                         |
 | We’ll first need to determine exactly which UPS you have by collecting the model and serial number from its bottom or rear panel. It will be found on a white, rectangular sticker with two barcodes. |
 | Please enter your Model Number from the barcode sticker                                                                               |
And there shall be at least an embedded image in position "2" containing "UPSBarCode.jpg" file
```

I have written the Step definitions below

```
const timeout=60000
module.exports = function () {
    this.Given(/^a chat window "([^"]*)"$/, function (url) {
        return helpers.loadPage(url);
    })
    this.When(/^there shall be at least an embedded image in position "([^"]*)" containing "([^"]*)" file$/, function (position, jpgOrPng) {
        return page.apcupsTroubleshooting.expectImage(jpgOrPng, position, timeout);
    })
    this.Then(/the text displayed in position "([^"]*)" shall contain following statements$/, function (position, table) {
        table.rows().forEach(function (option, index) {
            console.log("checking " + option);
            return page.apcupsTroubleshooting.expectChatbotText(option[0], position, timeout);
        });
    })
};
```

Here is my Page objects

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;

module.exports = {
    url: 'localhost:3000/',
    elements: {
        textInput: by.name("inputText"),
        textOutputs: by.className("message")
    },
/**
 * types something in chatbot
 * @param {any} userInput
 */
    typeMessage: function (userInput) {
        console.log("Going to type '" + userInput + "'");
        var selector = page.apcupsTroubleshooting.elements.textInput;
        return driver.findElement(selector).sendKeys(userInput, selenium.Key.ENTER);
    },

    expectChatbotText: function (text, position, timeout) {
        console.log("checking '" + text + "'");
        theXpath = "//div[@class='message']//p[contains(text(),\"" + text + "\")]";
        console.log("xpath:" + theXpath)
        return driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(by.xpath(theXpath)), timeout)
            .then(() => {
                driver.findElement(by.xpath(theXpath)).getText()
                    .then(t => {
                        try {
                            expect(t).to.contain(text)
                        }
                        catch (e)
                        {
                            return Promise.reject(false)
                        }
                    })
            })
    },

    expectImage: function (imageFile, position, timeout) {
        console.log("checking image " + imageFile + " existance in position " + position);
        theXpath = " //img[contains(@src,'" + imageFile + "')]";
        return driver.wait(
           until.elementsLocated(by.css('.cardImage')), timeout)
           .then(() => {
                console.log('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
                driver.FindElements(by.css('.cardImage'))
                    .then(t => {
                        console.log('yyyyyyyyyyyyyy')
                        try {
                            expect(t[0].GetAttribute("src").ToString()).to.contain(imageFile)
                        }
                        catch (e)
                        {
                            return Promise.reject(false)
                        }
                    })
            })
    },

    checkOptionElement: function (option, position, timeout) {
        console.log("checking list entry " + option + " existance in frame " + position);
        theXpath = " //div[@class='card']/div/ul/li[contains(text(),\"" + option +"\")]";
        return driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(by.xpath(theXpath)), timeout)
            .then(() => {
                return driver.findElement(by.xpath(theXpath));
            })
    }
};
```

Here is my html page

```
<section class="messages-wrapper">
   <div class="messages">
      <div class="group group-bot" id="message-group-bot-1">
         <div>
            <div>
               <div class="messageParentContainer">
                  <div class="message">
                     <p>
                     <div>Hey there! I’m a bot that can help you troubleshoot issues with UPS.</div>
                     </p>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <div>
               <div class="">
                  <div class="message">
                     <p>
                     <div>We’ll first need to determine exactly which UPS you have by collecting the model and serial number from its bottom or rear panel. It will be found on a white, rectangular sticker with two barcodes.</div>
                     </p>
                     <div class="cardImageContainer"> <img class="cardImage" src="https://somedomain/UPSBarCode.jpg"></div>
                     <div class="hide-container"> <object class="videoFrame" data=""></object></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <div>
               <div class="messageParentContainer">
                  <div class="message">
                     <p>
                     <div>Please enter your Model Number from the barcode sticker</div>
                     </p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div style="float: left; clear: both;"></div>
   </div>
</section>
```

I have also tried

```
expectImage: function (imageFile, position, timeout) {
        console.log("checking image " + imageFile + " existance in position " + position);
        theXpath = " //img[contains(@src,'" + imageFile + "')]";
        return driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(by.xpath(theXpath)), timeout)
            .then(() => {
                return driver.findElement(by.xpath(theXpath));
            })
    },
```

So my problem is, I am not able to detect the Image so that the tests are failing. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the issue just by inspection, but a few things you could try:

- Use `FindElement` instead of `FindElements`.  `FindElement` will (helpfully) fail immediately if the element is not found, instead of happily finding nothing and passing an empty array downstream to fail in a more confusing way later.
- I've had issues where the page simply wasn't in the expected state when the assertion ran, which is really frustrating when you look at the page a few milliseconds later and it's *right there*.  You might try dumping the entire DOM to console just before the assertion (I think it's `driver.getPageSource()`, but don't quote me).

Some gratuitous, cheeky code review you didn't ask for (sorry):

- When I'm debugging, I find it tremendously helpful for the step definition to follow the same flow as the feature file, and to make sure each step has the same Given/When/Then prefix in both places (it's kind of a nit, but you have a Then as a When currently).
- Sometimes a whole set of problems will go away if you keep your regex as narrow as possible.  I doubt this is related to your immediate problem, but those position number capture groups could be defined to only accept digits (`%d+`), and then you could even drop the double quotes if you prefer.
- I've had great luck defining locators (e.g. `by.css('.cardImage')`) in a single location of the page object, so they aren't duplicated

Comment: FYI I have already tried the FindElement. It did not work. Also I have done driver.getPageSource().then(function(value) {
       console.log(value);     
 }); Which does not even print the value and it times out.